# Snowflake lateral flatten with changing keys in json

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, lateral

I have a table  in Snowflake with similar structure as below,

```
----------------------------------------
Name | Number
----------------------------------------
Dim_1 | {'Table_1': 100}
Dim_1 | {'Table_1': 101}
Dim_2 | {'Table_2': 200, 'Table_3': 300}
Dim_2 | {'Table_2': 201, 'Table_3': 301}
```

and I am trying to get output as :

```
-----------------------
Name | Table | Entries
-----------------------
Dim_1 | Table_1 | 100
Dim_1 | Table_1 | 101
Dim_2 | Table_2 | 200
Dim_2 | Table_3 | 300
Dim_2 | Table_2 | 201
Dim_2 | Table_3 | 301
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! You should consider showing us what you have done so far to try and solve the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward application of the [`FLATTEN` function](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) can work here. The function creates a lateral view with exploded rows from each source row. For flat objects, all key value pairs are exploded into one row each.

Using the `KEY` portion of the flattened result provides the `Table` part of the desired output, and the `VALUE` portion provides `Entries`. Since `FLATTEN` produces a lateral view, you still have access to the preceding source table row values to continue retaining the `Name` column in the result.

An example query that performs the transformation:

```sql
SELECT
  t.name AS "Name",
  lv.key AS "Table",
  lv.value AS "Entries"
FROM
  data_table t,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => t.number) lv
```